# Calculate pi in python using multiple processes

Tags: python, algorithm, python-multiprocessing

Just for fun i'm trying to implement in python some algorithms to calculate pi. I managed to do such with the Gauss-Legendre algorithm and i'm quite satisfied. In spite of this, the Python process uses only one core (one process).

Here is the main section of my implementation:

```
from decimal import *
import math
import time

digit = 10000
getcontext().prec = digit+1

am, a, b, t, p = 0, 1, 1/Decimal(2).sqrt(), Decimal(1/4), 1

while am != a:

    am, bm, tm, pm = a, b, t, p

    a = Decimal((am+bm)/2)
    b = Decimal(am*bm).sqrt()
    t = Decimal(tm-pm*(am-a)**2)
    p = 2*pm

pi = Decimal((a+b)**2/(4*t))
print(pi)
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign to each process the calculation of a, b, t, p.

I've looked at the multiprocess documentation but looks like it suit only with iterative tasks like sums (example Ramanujan algorithm).

Thanks

Comment: The general issue here is how to parallelise this algorithm. You can easily have each CPU run in parallel and do the same thing, but that's obviously useless. You want each CPU to solve a *different* part of the problem at the same time; so how do you *subdivide* this algorithm into individual tasks which can be solved in parallel and which would speed up the calculation of the end result? And that question is probably a bit too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Actually i think that it could be parallelized by assigning to each process the calculation of each variable.

Comment: *If* that will actually speed up the overall result... There's a certain overhead associated with coordinating multiple threads, and the operation is so tiny that it may or may not be outstripped by that overhead. You can certainly try it and see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like a problem that you can easily parallelize into smaller problems that can run independently of one another. You could create a thread to execute each of them individually, but you won't be able to calculate them in parallel since they're dependent on each other (you'd have to wait for a to be calculated before b and so forth).

And so if you're running them in the original order where the threads have to wait for each other, then it's not really any different from running them sequentially as you did above.